Bathroom remodel - pulling subfloor
I need to pull the subfloor in an upstairs bathroom to re-arrange the drain location. I imagine the plumber is going to cut a section out (rather than the full sheet). The thing that has me worried however, is that when I go to put the subfloor back in, it will require some blocking to support where I cut it out. I have those engineered I-joists, and so where do I attach the blocking? It seems like you're not supposed to attach to the flanges, so I'm a bit confused.

The only scenario where blocking would be required to replace the subfloor is if you cut out a narrow strip parallel to and in between two joists.   So your approach could be "don't do that".  Make your cuts over joists or across them.  Removing entire sheets is a great idea if it's not too hard. Still, there are other situations where you need blocking in floors especially around showers and tubs so your question is a good one.

Most sub floor seams are placed in the centre of the joists.  So even cutting at the edge, removing the extra ~3/4 inch of sub floor over the joist, should be easy.
